# Amazon ECS : how to schedule a container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

I have a very simple ECS cluster using Fargate. I'd like to schedule a container to be run using a cron expression.

I created the task definition and a rule pointing to it using the EventBridge console, but I see nothing getting launched on the cluster. No logs, not even a trace of anything starting apart from the "monitor" tab of the rule which says it was triggered (but then again, I don't see any logs).

I'm guessing this might have to do with the public IP somehow needed for the rule to pull the container using Fargate? In the creation there is a setting called `auto-assign public IP address` but it only shows the `DISABLED` option.

Has anyone had the same problem? Should I just schedule a normal service with sleep times of 24hours between executions and risk a higher cost? Cheers

Comment: Sadly your question is not clear. [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduling_tasks.html) provide detailed info on how to schedule a task. Did you fallow the docs?

Comment: Yes, I followed the docs... Not sure how I can make the question clearer.

Comment: You would need to provide details of your EB rule, such as what IAM role did you use? Does it have proper permissions to launch tasks?

Comment: "I'm guessing this might have to do with the public IP somehow needed for the rule to pull the container using Fargate" that is not a thing that exists. CloudWatch rules don't need public IP addresses. First, try running the task manually to see if you get any errors, if that works, then it is most likely an IAM role configuration issue, where CloudWatch doesn't have permission to run the task.

Comment: I'm doing everything with the root account. On the below link it is said that network configuration is required for fargate. I am just specifying the same subnets (some public some not) and sec group as my fargate cluster... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html . No problem running the task manually in the cluster, already checked, it's just that eventbridge isn't starting it

Comment: You might want to check CloudTrail for any failure logs. I see this all the time when I don't have the IAM role configured correctly that EventBridge assumes in order to create your ECS task.

Comment: @gaut let me know if my solution worked for you

Comment: It's an absolute nightmare. I was at least able to run services, but I might have deleted a cloudwatch log group, and now I get `failed to create Cloudwatch log stream: ResourceNotFoundException: The specified log group does not exist. : exit status 1`. I hesitate to legit close my account on this fucking website.

Comment: @gaut did you manage to run the task with EventBridge? Can you confirm that the issue was a permissions issue?

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention that you have no issues running the task manually in the cluster, it's likely that the problem with EventBridge is that the role associated with the rule does not have enough permissions to run the task.

You can confirm this by checking CloudTrail logs. You'll find a `RunTask` event with a failure similar to the following:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::xxxx:assumed-role/Amazon_EventBridge_Invoke_ECS/xxx is not authorized to perform: ecs:RunTask on resource: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxxx:task-definition/ECS_task
```